# Passing Android Java Strings to Node.js Server and then into PostgreSQL

Tags: java, android, string, postgresql, quotes

**Problem**: Strings in Java use double quotes like "  ".  I'm unable to insert these strings into the database, as PostgreSQL uses single quotes as in '  ' for strings.  In PostgreSQL, double quotes are used as identifiers.

I have some poor solutions that I've seen online such as using $$ for the strings but would that entail me taking each variable I get an converting it.  I really don't want to just surround my strings with dollar signs and then have the strings in my database have quotes around them from now on.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding dollar signs in your node.js file around your strings won't add double quotes or dollar signs into your database unnecessarily.